# No response from google apis when fetching from iid.google api when using firebase cloud messaging for web

Tags: javascript, firebase, api

I can't get response from the iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1.When i log the error obj,it returns promise obj.It outputs like that

> 'firebase-messaging.js:123 Error subscribing to topic: 200 - [object
>   Promise]'.

I log the response obj and it is empty obj.It's already working in previous,serverkey and topics are still good.

```
function sendTokenToServer(token) {
  if (token && typeof token == "string") {
     /* if($('#webtoken').length){
        $('#webtoken').val(token);
      }
*/
    fetch("https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/" + token + "/rel/topics/" + topic, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: new Headers({
        "Authorization": "key=" + serverKey
      })
    }).then(function(response) {
      if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 400 || Object.keys(response).length === 0) {
        throw "Error subscribing to topic: "+response.status + " - " + response.text();
      }
      console.log('Subscribed to "'+topic+'"');
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
  }
}
```

> firebase-messaging.js:42 Service worker registration success.
>   firebase-messaging.js:46 Notification permission granted.
>   firebase-messaging.js:50 Token.
>   f6DFtPXpMCs:APA91bF5ITXU67mnXF9yq6TGlgniYU2WgDwIMhEiJglHLIm1ArVIY_gJzKEOu3I_WF3MYutRx9GD6kh4HTBmDvarI7WGAY_OQEyeRCnh7JLhlvHHnB3s0lVgzg76AoSzFVWBNMCzKiXC